# Get nodeIds of elements within iframe using chrome dev tools protocol

Tags: puppeteer, chrome-devtools-protocol

Chrome Devtools Protocol `DOM.querySelectorAll` returns all nodeIs of the elements in the html. But it does not return the id's of the iframe contents. Is there a way to get them ?

```js
const doc = await page._client.send('DOM.getDocument');
const result = await page._client.send('DOM.querySelectorAll', {nodeId: doc.root.nodeId, selector: '*'});
```

```html
<!-- Host Page -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
    <div>Hello World</div>
    <iframe src="demo.html" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</body>
</html>


<!-- IFrame Page -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
    <!-- I need to access this div from dev tools -->
    <div>Demo Page</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/imaman/cd7c943e0831a447b1d2b073ede347e2)

```js
async function findElementInIframe(DOM, iframeSelector, elementSelector) {
    const doc = await DOM.getDocument({depth: 0});

    const iframeQueryResult = await DOM.querySelector({nodeId: doc.root.nodeId, selector: iframeSelector});
    const iframeDescription = await DOM.describeNode({nodeId: iframeQueryResult.nodeId});

    const contentDocRemoteObject = await DOM.resolveNode({backendNodeId: iframeDescription.node.contentDocument.backendNodeId});
    const contentDocNode = await DOM.requestNode({objectId: contentDocRemoteObject.object.objectId});

    const elementQueryResult = await DOM.querySelector({nodeId: contentDocNode.nodeId, selector: elementSelector});
    return await DOM.describeNode({nodeId: elementQueryResult.nodeId});
}
```

Comment: This works most of the time, but doesn't seem to work when the iframe is from another origin and "contentDocument" isn't available